# How can I fix this program dealing with pairs of Booleans in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For part of a homework assignment in a beginner Haskell course, I'm trying to write a program that will take a list of pairs of Bools, and returns a list of Bools coming from the pairs of bools with an "&&" between them. For example...

```
andandbool [(True,True),(True,False),(False,True),(False,False)]
```

would return:

```
[True, False, False, False]
```

I keep running into trouble, however. My code looks like this.

```
andandbool :: [(Bool,Bool)] -> [Bool]
andandbool [a] = [fst x && snd x | x <- [a]]
```

It works fine when I provide a list of only one pair, but reports "Non-exhaustive patterns in function andandbool" when I enter a list of multiple pairs. Is there some sort of list comprehension that I'm missing? Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider that `[a]` IS a list of only one element (pair, in your case).  On other hand any arbitrary variable, such as `a`, can be a list of any number of elements...

Comment: Replace `[a]` in your code with `as`.  The brackets are reserved syntax for a list with exactly one element.

Comment: Thank you both very much, I never knew that! It was very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Now that I'm at my computer I'll turn my comment into an answer.

When you name the argument of the function `[a]`, Haskell interprets that as your function pattern matching on a list of one element.  That's why your function only worked on one-element lists.  To fix it, just rename the function argument to something without brackets in the name:

```
andandbool :: [(Bool,Bool)] -> [Bool]
andandbool as = [fst x && snd x | x <- as]
```

That `as` argument will now match any list.

Edit: Like @Ankur mentioned, you can simplify this as:

```
andandbool as = [x && y | (x, y) <- as]
```

If you really want to play code golf you can simplify this even more as:

```
andandbool = map (uncurry (&&))
```

Comment: A bit of pattern matching .. `[x && y | (x,y) <- as]`